# Dynamic running total

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to create a view that returns months of rain amt totals.  Each row returned by the view would represent a month for a given year.

In the view I would like to include a column that is the cumulative rain over the year, such that a row for January would have the total rain amt for January of that yr. The rows for Feb would have the rain amt total for `Jan+Feb` of that yr,  rows for Mar would have rain amt total for `Jan+Feb+Mar`... and so on up to Dec.  Dec would have the total rain for the year.

The tough part is I would like to be able to query the view for a specific date 
ex. "`select * from vw_rain_stats where rain_date >= to_date('2010-MAR-01')`" and the cumulative sum total column should begin cumulating from the month specified in the where clause (March), not January.

I don't want any monthly rain amts from prior to 2010-MAR-01 to be included in the data returned by the view.

I can develop a view that cumulates amts for the whole yr but I can not figure out how to develop the view so that it can begin cumulating amts for a month other than January.

Given there is data for Jan 2012 thru to Feb 2013 in the underlying table and for each month in that time period there is some rain (no zero rain mths).

```
create table rain_stats (rain_date date, amt number);

insert into rain_stats values ('2012-JAN-01', 50);
insert into rain_stats values ('2012-FEB-01', 10);
insert into rain_stats values ('2012-MAR-01', 20);
insert into rain_stats values ('2012-APR-01', 40);
insert into rain_stats values ('2012-MAY-01', 30);
insert into rain_stats values ('2012-JUN-01', 10);
insert into rain_stats values ('2012-JUL-01', 4);
insert into rain_stats values ('2012-AUG-01', 100);
insert into rain_stats values ('2012-SEP-01', 5);
insert into rain_stats values ('2012-OCT-01', 100);
insert into rain_stats values ('2012-NOV-01', 90);
insert into rain_stats values ('2012-DEC-01', 80);
insert into rain_stats values ('2013-JAN-01', 30);
insert into rain_stats values ('2013-FEB-01', 7);
```

The user executes this query

`select * from vw_rain_stats where rain_date >= '2012-MAY-01'`

This is the result that is returned;

```
|          RAIN_DATE | AMT | RUNNING_AMT |
------------------------------------------
|      May, 01 2012  |  30 |          30 |
|      Jun, 01 2012  |  10 |          40 |
|      Jul, 01 2012  |   4 |          44 |
|      Aug, 01 2012  | 100 |         144 |
|      Sep, 01 2012  |   5 |         149 |
|      Oct, 01 2012  | 100 |         249 | 
|      Nov, 01 2012  |  90 |         339 |
|      Dec, 01 2011  |  80 |         419 |
|      Jan, 01 2013  |  30 |          30 |
|      Feb, 01 2013  |  70 |         100 |
| .................. | ... | ........... |
```

Notice that the rain amts for Jan-Apr 2012 are not included in the resultset or in the running_amt cumulative values.  This is what I want to happen.

Comment: Can you add a quick sample of the table format and the desired output?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED** Are you looking for this?

```
CREATE VIEW vw_rain_stats
AS
  SELECT TRUNC(rain_date, 'MM') rain_date,
         SUM(amt) amt
    FROM rain_stats
   GROUP BY TRUNC(rain_date, 'MM')
;
```

Get monthly amounts for 2012 year

```
SELECT rain_date,
       amt,
       SUM(amt) OVER (ORDER BY rain_date) running_amt
  FROM vw_rain_stats
 WHERE rain_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-12' AND '01-DEC-12';
```

Get monthly amounts starting with December 2011

```
SELECT rain_date,
       amt,
       SUM(amt) OVER (ORDER BY rain_date) running_amt
  FROM vw_rain_stats
 WHERE rain_date >= '01-DEC-11';
```

Sample output:

```
|          RAIN_DATE | AMT | RUNNING_AMT |
------------------------------------------
| December, 01 2011  |  80 |          80 |
|  January, 01 2012  |  30 |         110 |
| February, 01 2012  |  70 |         180 |
|    March, 01 2012  | 110 |         290 |
| .................. | ... | ........... |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f550a/5)** demo

Comment: @DarcyDommer Updated answer and sqlfiddle. You are free to choose any time interval with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this.  You have the right idea but I want the sum implementation to be in the view definition.  I don't want the user to need to know that part.  The view query should be as simple as "select rain_date, amt, running_amt from vw_rain_stats where rain_date >= '01-MAR-2012'"

Comment: So you'd probably want a stored procedure that passes the date variable to the query above that references the view.

Comment: @peterm, if you add the analytic sum() to the view definition and (from the OPs data it looks like they want) a `PARTITION BY trunc(rain_date, 'y')` in there you've got exactly what the OP is after.

Comment: I thought that would work but it doesn't return the answer I want. If the user enters something like rain_date >= '01-MAR-2012' the analytic fn applies itself before the where clause entered by the user so the running_amt for the first row returned includes rain amts for jan and feb. I only want running_amt to incl mar in the first row returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I follow exactly what you're after, but it sounds like a situation where you'd want a Window function.  If you add this to your view:

```
SUM(Rain_Amt) OVER (ORDER BY rain_date) AS cum_Rain
```

You could get the cumulative rainfall starting from any date, by subtracting the cumulative rainfall of your start date from each subsequent date, something like:

```
SELECT *, cum_Rain - (SELECT cum_Rain FROM vw_rain_stats WHERE rain_date = '20070405')
FROM vw_rain_stats
WHERE rain_date >= '20070405'
```

Comment: Thanks.  you've got the right idea but I'm trying to figure out how to put all the summation implementation in the view definition. All I want the user to need to do is provide a date.  Given that date, the view will return a resultset sorted by year and month.  It should start accumulating the rain amts from the first row (or month) in the resultset and reset the accumulating after the first Dec row.  Then start accumulating again all over again for each row until the next Dec row. and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you have an underlying table `RainDays` which is daily rain amounts.

You would think that what you want is the following view:

```
create view vw_RainMonths as
    select yyyymm, RainMonth,
            sum(RainMonth) over (order by yyyymm) as cum
    from (select to_char(RainDate as 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, sum(Rain) as RainMonth
          from RainDays
          group by to_char(RainDate as 'YYYY-MM')
         ) t
```

However, this doesn't work, because (as you suspect) it accumulates the values from the beginning of time.  The `where` clause applies to this data.

Oracle does support for table-valued functions, parameterized views, and pipelined table functions -- all of which can act as taking a view and applying a value in an argument.  Unfortunately, none of these are as clean as a single view.  They require creating a new data type for the return value.

Comment: Yes.  Is there a way to get the sum analytical to be applied after the where clause is evaluated?

Comment: @DarcyDommer . . . Basically, there are ways but they are not quite as simple as adding a view.

Comment: I had thought I could get where I wanted using windowing and partitions and some combination of sum, lag, preceding, following, current row.  But no luck.