# Sum the results of case statement in a new column Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have just started using an Oracle system after learning SQL, querying and RDBMS functionality in MS Access, so please bear with me. I have created a query using case statements to pivot a database column and sum balances, which is working fine, like this:

```
Date    Disbursed Repaid
3/1/17  -1000     500
3/2/17  -2500     1500
```

What I need to do is add a column called "Net" which sums both disbursed and repaid amounts for each date. I've done some digging and the solution seems to be the use of an OVER() clause, but every example I have found is overly simplistic and I can't figure out how to translate that into my own query. Here is a sample of the case statement in my query:

```
SELECT TableA.ACTDATETIME as "Date",

sum( case when tableA.code='NDSB' then tableA.amt end) AS Disbursed,
sum( case when tableA.code='SPMT' then tableA.amt end) AS Repaid
```

The output I am looking for looks like this:

```
 Date    Disbursed Repaid Net
 3/1/17  -1000     500    -500
 3/2/17  -250      1500   1250
```

What is the best way of doing this?

EDIT: Stretch goal - I'd like to create a running total of the newly created "Net" column

Answer (score 3):

You would use analytic queries (`over`) if you wanted to do group values from multiple rows while retaining individual row values. That's not what you're doing.

There are two ways to go about this:

First, you could simply add the two cases together:

```
SELECT   tablea.actdatetime AS actdate,
         SUM (CASE WHEN tablea.code = 'NDSB' THEN tablea.amt END) AS disbursed,
         SUM (CASE WHEN tablea.code = 'SPMT' THEN tablea.amt END) AS repaid,
           COALESCE(SUM (CASE WHEN tablea.code = 'NDSB' THEN tablea.amt END), 0)
         + COALESCE(SUM (CASE WHEN tablea.code = 'SPMT' THEN tablea.amt END), 0)
             AS net
FROM     tablea
GROUP BY actdatetime
```

Or, if you don't want to repeat the `case` statements, you could use a subquery:

```
SELECT actdate,
       disbursed,
       repaid,
       COALESCE(disbursed, 0) + COALESCE(repaid, 0) AS net
FROM   (SELECT   tablea.actdatetime AS actdate,
                 SUM (CASE WHEN tablea.code = 'NDSB' THEN tablea.amt END)
                     AS disbursed,
                 SUM (CASE WHEN tablea.code = 'SPMT' THEN tablea.amt END)
                     AS repaid
        FROM     tablea
        GROUP BY actdatetime)
```

There's unlikely to be a performance difference between the two, so choose whichever you like better.

---

Looking at your query a little closer, there's a third option in this case. Since you're summing the same column in both `case` statement, the `case` for the `net` could simply include both values:

```
SELECT   tablea.actdatetime AS actdate,
         SUM (CASE WHEN tablea.code = 'NDSB' THEN tablea.amt END) AS disbursed,
         SUM (CASE WHEN tablea.code = 'SPMT' THEN tablea.amt END) AS repaid,
         SUM (CASE WHEN tablea.code IN ('NDSB', 'SPMT') THEN tablea.amt END)
             AS net
FROM     tablea
GROUP BY actdatetime
```

Comment: Thanks! Option A works but does not sum if there is a null value for either Disbursed or Repaid.Option B does not work, which is probably my fault because I have several joins I didnt mention for my WHERE clause. Option C worked perfectly, and was the easiest. It would sum even if there was a null value in either the Disbursed or Repaid column.

Comment: I've edited the answer to make the first two solutions work if either `sum` returns a null.

Comment: Option A works correctly now, but I still prefer option C as it is the most easily changed if I need to change the codes. You wouldn't happen to know how to create a running total of the Net column, would you?

Comment: For a running total, you are going to want to use an analytic function. If you want it group by dates still, then you'll need to use the `group by` in a sub-query, since you can't combine aggregates and analytic functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115722/how-to-calculate-running-total-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to wrap it an outer query

```sql
SELECT q.*, repaid - disbursed AS net
  FROM (
    -- your query goes in here
) q
```

Comment: Could I do the essentially the same thing for a running total of Net column, using the 3rd option laid out by @Allan above and OVER() partition by?